# How do I typecast model to another model and display to the view?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have a object Called Cars and it has some linked elements and I want to display them properly by type casting it.

```
Car()
{
   Id {get ; set;}
   Name {get ; set;}
   SpareParts{ get; set;}
}

SpareParts()
{
   CarId{get; set;}
   Car{get;set;}
   SparePart{get; set;}
   SparePartId {Get;set;}
}
```

But the SparePart Link item Original model will be like below

```
SparePart()
{
   Id{get; set;}
   Name { get; set; }
   Description { get; set; }
   ParentId { get ; set;}
}
```

And I have  separate View functionality (using Db view operation this view gets created using the parent id the full path of the name will be generated)

```
SparePartView : SparePart
{
ParentName {get;set;}
}
```

For example if SparePart 1 is Break and if it parent is Clutch then that parent name will be "Clutch\Break"

So while displaying the main object I have the SpareParts object and Sparepart link but I will not have the SparePart view which I need to display that name with full parent details.

So if I even fetch separately from the DB by fetching the Id's of spare parts then I need to properly map with the original item in the View(Razor Engine).

How to do this operation without so many for or for each loops.

```
ExporttoView()
{
var cars = carRepository.GetCarsForExport(SearchParameters);
_carRepository.LoadSpareObjects(cars) 
}
```

Now the Cars object will loaded with list of car entities and list of SpareObjects which is mapped to it.

For Example:
Car[0] will be like below

```
Id - 1
Name - BMW
SpareParts{CarId=1, Car - CarObject, SparePart(Id,Name,Description,ParentId), SparePartId}
```

But when I am going to view I need to display with Full name. In order to get the Fullnames of the Spare Parts I can do a db fetch.

```
var fullnameobjects = _SpareRepository.Get(Sparepart.Ids) // This will fetch full name of the list of spare parts objects.
```

I want to display it in the view like below.

```
Name : CarName,
Id : ID,
SparePartFull Name : Full path of the name for the spare parts.
```

I can achieve this by doing foreach loop like

```
Foreach(var item in Spareparts)
   {
   foreach(var name in fullnameListitems)
     {
      if(item.Id == name.Id)
      FullName= name.FullName
     }
   }
```

Comment: Could you update your question with enough code to reproduce the "error"? You have not listed a single for loop in "what you have tried already". 

So it is not very clear what you specifically want to change/optimize.

Comment: If I were you, I would look up "Unit of Work" pattern, and "Repository" pattern. 

Perhaps also "Dependency Injection". 

This will likely guide you to a solution you can use.

Comment: @MortenBork Please check my example code which I have updated now.

Comment: My point is, your query from the DB should contain all the data already, you should not have to "reprocess" the query result after the query has been executed. I suggest you use an ORM like entity-framework, and a relationship based DB. 

Your query from the ORM would look like:
 
List<Car> resultList = context.cars.Include(car => car.spareParts).ThenInclude(spareParts => spareParts.Sparepart).ToList();

Then the "Car" object will contain the objects you desire. 
This is the result of accessing the database via a "unit-of-work" and "repository" pattern.

Comment: If you use an interface, to say "set full name" on retrieval, and make sure that this is implemented on your ORM model, then you would not need to make a for-each at all, the method would just exist on model .

Like "SparePart : IGetFullName (where IGetFullname is a method that returns string, and takes a Sparepart as parameter)

Then you recursively progross through the spareparts, and build up the full name. 
and iff the parameter is null, you just take name "This" and only call the method, if the sub-part is not null. That should work.

Comment: @MortenBork Thanks for the idea, I got some clarity now. I will try to implement in the same way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just followed the above comment and modified the Reportsitory method for fetching the spare item. Since it is same objects inherited from SpareObject to SpareObjectView so default typecasting was allowed.

```
  var SpareobjectsViews = _spareRepository.GetSpareViews(CarIds).ToDictionary(x => x.Id + ":" + x.ProdId, x => x);
```

Assigned the same to Car Object in this way.

```
Cars.SpareObject = SpareObjectViews;
```

And in view, I have modified the code like this.

```
Cars.SpareObject as SpareObjectsView

SpareName = Cars.SpareObjectViewName
```